# Creating a bluetooth server with reflection method android

Tags: android

I need to have an android bluetooth server application. I've successfully created a client which use the reflection method like this:

```
Method m = zee.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
sock = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
```

But is there any way I can adapt this codesnippet so my device can act as a server instead of a client?

Answer (score 0):

If your using two android devices you can just create a server not using relection and using uuids instead. There is a general uuid that most devices use (like bluetooth modules. Sorry your gonna have to look for it or look at my previous questions) but using a uuid is a lot easier.

Comment: I'am not trying to connect to android devices. I have a android device, which will act as a server and another bluetooth device which will be the client. The client should send some files to my phone over the obex protocol, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: You can still use a uuid however. There's a general one that world with most devices. Ill find it out for you if you want. Generally you will need to initiate the connection some how. So you probably need to connect to the device instead of it connecting to you.